# How to change default name in form Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have this builder at FormType class:

```
$builder
->add('fkTblSources', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'BlaBlaBundle:TblSources',
    'property' => 'name',
))

->add('save', 'submit');`
```

This form shows `"fkTblSources"` as name of row. I need to put this name because it is the field name of the entity "TblTicket" that i want to create with this form.

How can I change this name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's easy, sorry.

Name of field is changed by 'label' option.

`->add('fkTblSources', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'BlaBlaBundle:TblSources',
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => 'name for field here'
))`